# Fastest Decompression Algorithm?

Tags: compression, snappy

I heard Google snappy is a fast de/compression library. What does Snappy library use as their algorithm? Is there some algorithm that is faster in decompressing? The compression rate and encoding is not my interest, but real time decompression is of my interest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[lz4](http://www.lz4.org/) is faster and in widespread use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check lz4 too :)